# editable html table with dynamic data dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, html-table

I have a table here which is editable so that we can add a row or delete the selected row here .

providing the code for the same :

```
<table id="dataTable">

                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Property</th>
                            <th>Value</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)" /></td>
                                <td>Type </td>
                                <td id="nodeType"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)" /></td>
                                <td id="property1Value">Property 1</td>
                                <td id="property1">
                                    <select id="dropDownValue">
                                        <option value="null">null</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)" /></td>
                                <td id="property2Value">Property 2</td>
                                <td id="property2">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="getRow(this)" /></td>
                                <td id="property3">dataSourceName</td>
                                <td id="property3Value">
                                    <select id="dropDownValue">
                                        <option value="null">null</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

i have two function add and delete row :

while adding a row i need to add a column which have checkbox and a input and a drop down , the issue i am facing here is the dropdown options are dynamic and generated by an api call so i am constructing the select options something like this ::

```
  const dataSet= ['a' , 'b', 'c']

    var select = document.getElementById("dropDownValue");  
          var opt = document.createElement('option');
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
                    var optn = dataSet[i];
                    var el = document.createElement("option");
                    el.textContent = optn;
                    el.value = optn;
                    select.appendChild(el);
                }
```

but this dropdown is not getting populated for all the tr's and comes only for one tr in the table

and i am trying to add this select while adding rows also : here is the addRow function

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name = "chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);


    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("select");
    //element3.type = "text";
    //element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are using document.getElementById to get the select element. This will only fetch the first select, in case there are multiple selects with the same id. It would be better to programmatically create both the select tag and option tag.

Comment: Thankyou Jatin , i will try that out now

Comment: That works :D thankyou so much for the trigger